# React app doesn't serve image assets on production

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm pretty much new in deploying React apps and I have a problem. Locally, the image assets in /src/app/assets are working fine, but when the app is deployed are 404 Not Found. My research got me to a conclusion that this might be a common issue if Webpack isn't configured properly, so I'm asking for help if anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong here.

My webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path');

var DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist');
var SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');

var config = {
  entry: SRC_DIR + '/app/index.js',
  output: {
    path: DIST_DIR + '/app',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/app/'
  },
  module: {
   loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.js?/,
      include: SRC_DIR,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      query: {
        presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-2']
      }
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
    },
    {
      test: /\.png$/,
      loader: "url-loader?limit=100000"
    },
    {
      test: /\.jpg$/,
      loader: "file-loader"
    }
  ]
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

And I have these scripts in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "npm run build",
   "build": "webpack -d && cp src/index.html dist/index.html && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline",
   "build:prod": "webpack -p && cp src/index.html dist/index.html"
 },
```

Thanks!